# How to find the number of uppercase words in a text, using ubuntu grep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find the number of uppercase words in a text file by using ubuntu terminal 'grep' command..
I already tried with `grep -c [[:upper:]] a.txt` command. But it count words which have simple characters also.

My text: *I am Tom PERERA*

My command line output should 2, that the words are "**I**" and "**PERERA**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the `-c` flag only returns the number of lines that were matched. If you have more than a single match per line it will give you incorrect results. I typically do something like this:

```
echo 'I am Tom PERERA' | grep -oE '\b[A-Z]+\b' | wc -l
```

Note: you can also use `'\b[[:upper:]]+\b'` if you prefer the POSIX classes

EDIT:
As @tripleee points out, the POSIX class `[:upper:]` will span locales and is a more portable solution.

Comment: `grep -oc` should count occurrences in one go. Older versions of GNU Coreutils had a bug so this didn't work properly, but if you have a recent version, this would be an obvious improvement.

Comment: I only get 1 result when I tried `-ocE`, do you know what version it was corrected in? I have version 2.19

Comment: `[[:upper:]]` would be better than `[A-Z]` because it's portable across locales (for example, `GÖTTERDÄMMERUNG` should register as all uppercase, especially if you have a German locale).

Comment: +1; FreeBSD `grep` 2.51 (current as of OS X 10.9.3 and FreeBSD 10) also only returns 1 with `-c` (counts only matching input _lines_).

Comment: You might want to add `-w` to count actual words, and not just lines.

Comment: @thg435 the `-o` flag writes every match out on a separate line.